# Convert Key object to PrivateKey

Tags: android, keystore

I need to use following method from KeyStore class:

`public Key getPrivateKey(String alias)`

But on the end I need PrivateKey object, not Key. How can I convert Key object to PrivateKey?
Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK it's safe to cast Key to PrivateKey.

Answer (score 2):

```
//get keystore 
//jks for type "JKS",
//.p12 or .pfx for type "PKCS12"
//specification name is PKCS#12, but the # is not used in the Java keystore type name
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
//load keystore - is FileImputStream to location of your pfx/jks file          
keystore.load(is, password);
//get private key           
PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey)keystore.getKey(alias, password);
```

Answer (score 0):

After you key the key from your key store 
create key pair and then get the pub and priv key from the pair key as following:

```
Key prvkey = keyStore.getKey(_alias,_keypass.toCharArray());
PublicKey pubkey = certificate.getPublicKey();
KeyPair keypair = new KeyPair(pubkey, (PrivateKey)prvkey);
PrivateKey privKewy = keypair.getPrivate();
```